# Invoke method with Codeigniter rendering view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Got a small problem with CodeIgniter and my view. See the code below. I'm generating a table with data coming from teh database. Now I want to add 2 buttons to edit or delete the row. But I'm stuck on what I need to do here. Obviously it's an MVC framework so I cannot call methods from my view. But how can I generate a link to let me delete the user by ID with a press on the button?

```
foreach($userlist as $val){
                echo "<div class='record'>
                        <div class='boxtable' id='boxone'>". $val['id'] ."</div>
                        <div class='boxtable' id='boxtwo'>". $val['username'] ."</div>
                        <div class='boxtable' id='buttonrecordbalk'>
                            <a href='#' class='btn' id='edituser'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></i></a>
                            <a href='users/delete_user?".$val['id'] ."' class='btn' id='deleteuser'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>
                        </div>
                        </div>";

            }
```

The delete user is something I'm focusing on right now. I've tried multiple things like

```
<a href='users/delete_user?".$val['id'] .' class='btn' id='deleteuser'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>
```

Here is my controller

```
function delete_user($id)
{
    $this->user->delete_user($id);
}
```

Model:

```
  function delete_user($id)
  {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    if($this->db->delete('app_users'))
    {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: you can use ajax for delete

Comment: It isn't possible to let it render and use href to delete?

Comment: use base_url() while making url and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own  tag and insert a url in the href like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>
```

or simply use the URL helper this way :

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

For more info on [URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

**EDIT**

To use the URL helper first load it .

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Does not work: $idding = $val['id'];                                                                  <a href='". site_url('users/delete_user/'.$idding.'') ."' class='btn' id='deleteuser'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a> I get a 404 error page not found

Comment: Do you have any page 'delete_user' ??

Comment: No! It's a method in my CodeIgniter controller, where I delete a user from the database...

Comment: Okay, Are you getting your $idding variable in that method ?

Comment: If you have not loaded the url helper then first load it and did you checked the link i provided for URL HELPER in answer ?

Comment: Thank you. Your comment led me to the solution. I did things right, but I needed to use this command: <a href='". site_url('usercontroller/delete_user?id='.$idding.'') ."' class='btn' id='deleteuser'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a> And I also had to put a GET in the controller, and not a post. Thanks!

Comment: Great, but it is possible the other way around also.